# Mixers and LO Harmonics

Tags: rf, mixer, harmonics, sdr

Say we have an RF signal with components at \$F_{LO}+\Delta\$ and \$3F_{LO}+\Delta\$ and we want to down-convert so that \$F_{LO}+\Delta\$ becomes \$\Delta\$. We will mix this RF signal with our local oscillator - a square wave oscillating between 1 and -1 - which has a frequency of \$F_{LO}\$. Due to it being a square wave it will have harmonics at odd multiples ie \$3F_{LO}\$, \$5F_{LO}\$, \$7F_{LO}\$, etc.

[image: Image of LO and S(t)]

This mixing will down-convert our signal to \$\Delta\$, as well as creating a lot of other sum and difference frequencies due to mixing with the LOs harmonics. The problem arises when we consider what happens when the component at \$3F_{LO}+\Delta\$ gets mixed with the \$3F_{LO}\$ harmonic, as it creates a difference frequency \$\Delta\$ and so will interfere with the signal we wanted to extract.

Is there a different way of mixing that solves this "image rejection" (not entirely sure that's the correct term) problem? I eventually want to use this to create a simple direct conversion receiver with IQ sampling, so I don't want to use filters on the RF side if possible so I can keep the frequency range as wide as possible.

Comment: One solution uses a strictly multiplying mixer, where the local oscillator is sinusoidal instead of switching mixers as OP describes...far fewer spurious outputs. You can still use two multipliers for I/Q if you can generate two quadrature local oscillator signals for each. This solution is not commonly seen in the wild.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I found what I was looking for. I don't really know the terminology too well but by brute force searching I found "Harmonic Rejection Mixers" along with [this](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/brweb/papers/Journals/BR_SSCM_4_2018.pdf) article that explains them in good detail. It allows me to stick to using square waves and not using filters.

Comment: Another solution is to over-sample the RF signal with fast ADC(s), This is often difficult and/or expensive for high RF signal frequencies.